# S3 to Dynamodb item logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am working on some data stuff. Where I am transferring/importing csv data from s3 to my DynamoDB table. Since the data is very huge it is very difficult to find any discrepancy in each row. Some-how my importing fails with error. `The provided key element does not match the schema` and the row it is telling me, is alright and does not have any weird values.

What I want to do now:
I want to some-how log each item that is taken from csv s3 to dynamodb. In this way I can find the row which made this error.

Is there anyway to log that?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: How are you importing the data right now?

Comment: @TobiasGeiselmann I am using aws datapipeline which uses HiveActivity to import data from S3 to DynamoDB.